# Изменить textSize заголовка в actionBar

Tags: android

Всем привет. Не могу найти как меняется размер заголовка текста в actionBar. Кто знает как это сделать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.Viadeo.Styled.YourTheme.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.YourTheme.Styled.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```